# Show 0 even if there are no records to display

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query I can't seem to perfect. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am attempting to show all of the communities in the results even if there are no records for that community.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(D.FulfillmentAmt),0) as Approved, DB.Budget, DC.CommunityName 
FROM Donations D
LEFT JOIN DCommunity DC ON D.Market = DC.CID
LEFT JOIN DBudget DB ON D.Market = DB.Community
WHERE D.StatusId = '1' AND DB.[Year] = year(getdate())
GROUP BY DC.CommunityName, DB.Budget
ORDER BY DC.CommunityName
```

Currently displays the following results:

```
Approved | Budget | CommunityName
10       | 2000   | City1
2400     | 3000   | City2
2358     | 5000   | City3
1855     | 2000   | City5
2200     | 3000   | City6
5600     | 7000   | City8
```

As you can see it is missing City4 and City7 because there are no records within the dbo.Donations table for those cities. I would still like those two to show up with the Approved amount of 0 even if they have no records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want all communities, as a matter of style, I'd always make that my first table in the join (easier for me to think through). Then you need to move the WHERE conditions into the JOIN clause appropriately because keeping them in the WHERE forces it to behave like an INNER JOIN. Also, the join on DBudget  needed updated to refer back to the DCommunity table.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(D.FulfillmentAmt),0) as Approved, DB.Budget, DC.CommunityName 
FROM DCommunity DC
LEFT JOIN DBudget DB ON DC.CID  = DB.Community AND DB.[Year] = year(getdate())
LEFT JOIN Donations D ON D.Market = DC.CID AND D.StatusId = '1'
GROUP BY DC.CommunityName, DB.Budget
ORDER BY DC.CommunityName
```

Comment: Don't just dump code. Explain what you changed and why too.

Comment: @Ghost This appears to be working! I am getting NULL for the Budget column for both City4 and City7 and both of those have budgets in the DBudget table for the current year. Let me double check my tables but this is definitely showing all of them.

Comment: @Ghost Is it possible to create another column called Declined that shows the SUM(D.FulfillmentAmt) for records with the D.StatusId = '2'? Trying to limit the amount of queries I am calling by combining everything into one.

Comment: @kcray Almost all things are possible. But you should post another question to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Then start your `left join` with `DCommunity`, if that is what you want to preserve.  Also, you need to move some conditions to `on` clauses, so the `left join` does not become an `inner`join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(D.FulfillmentAmt), 0) as Approved, DB.Budget, DC.CommunityName 
FROM DCommunity DC LEFT JOIN
     Donations D
     ON D.Market = DC.CID LEFT JOIN
     DBudget DB
     ON D.Market = DB.Community AND
        D.StatusId = '1' AND
        DB.[Year] = year(getdate())
GROUP BY DC.CommunityName, DB.Budget
ORDER BY DC.CommunityName;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "D.StatusId = '1'" clause be on the join clause of the donations table?

Comment: This displays the cities twice in some cases, with this I am seeing City2 twice with a Budget as NULL. It's showing all the cities but duplicating a lot of them with NULL in the Budget column.

Comment: @kcray . . . Perhaps you don't want `Budget` in the `group by`.  If it is there, it is because there is no match on `statusid` and `year` for that market.

Answer (score 2):

Move conditions from `WHERE` to `ON`, to get a real `LEFT JOIN`. (Otherwise you get a regular INNER JOIN...)

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(D.FulfillmentAmt),0) as Approved,
       DB.Budget,
       DC.CommunityName 
FROM DCommunity DC 
  LEFT JOIN Donations D ON D.Market = DC.CID AND D.StatusId = '1'
  LEFT JOIN DBudget DB ON D.Market = DB.Community AND DB.[Year] = year(getdate())
GROUP BY DC.CommunityName, DB.Budget
ORDER BY DC.CommunityName
```

Comment: I tried this one and it is still not showing the two cities that have no records.

Comment: If there were no donations for a community, this wouldn't return the community with 0 donations